# Use Linq to return first result for each category

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class (ApplicationHistory) with 3 properties:

> ApplicantId, ProviderId, ApplicationDate

I return the data from the database into a list, however this contains duplicate ApplicantId/ProviderId keys.

I want to supress the list so that the list only contains the the earliest Application Date for each ApplicantId/ProviderId.

The example below is where I'm currently at, but I'm not sure how to ensure the earliest date is returned.

```
    var supressed = history
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            ApplicantId = x.ApplicantId,
            ProviderId = x.ProviderId
        })
        .First();
```

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that each group formed by the `GroupBy` call is an `IGrouping<ApplicationHistory>`, which implements `IEnumerable<ApplicationHistory>`.  Read more about `IGrouping` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx).  You can order those and pick the first one:

```
var oldestPerGroup = history
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        ApplicantId = x.ApplicantId,
        ProviderId = x.ProviderId
    })
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationDate).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting first group. Instead select first item from each group:

```
var supressed = history
    .GroupBy(x => new {
        ApplicantId = x.ApplicantId,
        ProviderId = x.ProviderId
    })
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationDate).First());
```

Or query syntax (btw you don't need to specify names for anonymous object properties in this case):

```
var supressed = from h in history
                group h by new {
                  h.ApplicantId,
                  h.ProviderId
                } into g
                select g.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationDate).First();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How do I guarantee the earliest ApplicateDate though? - the query doesn't specify an order and it might not be guaranteed to be in ApplicationDate order from the Db

Comment: @dotnetnoob see Ben's answer, I just missed that part of your question